# Cause of error setting up Sign in with Apple for Firebase in Swift on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sign-in-with-apple

I have been following https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple and it does mention the error I am receiving re "sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string" but it doesn't offer any help to solve it and my searches haven't given me a solution which works.

My view controller code extract is

```
        fileprivate var currentNonce: String?

        @objc @available(iOS 13, *)
        func startSignInWithAppleFlow() {
          let nonce = randomNonceString()
          currentNonce = nonce
          let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
          let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
          request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
          request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
            print(request.nonce)

          let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
          authorizationController.delegate = self
          authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
          authorizationController.performRequests()
        }
        @available(iOS 13, *)
        private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
          let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
          let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
          let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
            return String(format: "%02x", $0)
          }.joined()
            print(hashString)
          return hashString
        }
    }
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    extension LoginViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

      func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
          guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
          }
          guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
            print("Unable to fetch identity token")
            return
          }
          guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
            print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
            return
          }
          // Initialize a Firebase credential.
            print(nonce)
            let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                      idToken: idTokenString,
                                                      accessToken: nonce)

            print(credential)
          // Sign in with Firebase.
          Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
              // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
              // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
              // your request to Apple.
                print(authResult)
                print(error!)
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
              return
            }
            // User is signed in to Firebase with Apple.
            // ...
          }
        }
      }
```

This section is different from the instructions on the webpage as Xcode gave an error

```
    let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                      idToken: idTokenString,
                                                      accessToken: nonce)
```

If I print the nonce immediately before

```
    let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                      idToken: idTokenString,
                                                      accessToken: nonce)
```

I get 2eNjrtagc024_pd3wfnt_PZ0N89GZ_b6_QJ3IZ_

response.nonce value is cd402f047012a2d5c129382c56ef121b53a679c0a5c5e37433bcde2967225afe

Obviously these aren't the same but I can't seem to work out what I am doing wrong.

Full error output is

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000388a820 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request.";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request.";
}}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}
An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same error.

Solution:
Just run

`pod update`

Explanation:

The problem is as @ethanrj says. The documentation says to do

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential( 
    withProviderID: "apple.com", IDToken: appleIdToken, rawNonce: rawNonce )
```

but this gives an error and Xcode will suggest the following (rawNonce -> accessToken):

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential( 
    withProviderID: "apple.com", IDToken: appleIdToken, accessToken: rawNonce )
```

This is because `pod install` will install FirebaseAuth 6.12 by default, when you really need 6.13 since the new function signature is only available there. You can view the source [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/OAuth/FIROAuthProvider.m).

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it, I should have thought of it myself!    End result which worked let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce, accessToken: nil)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you are using the wrong credential method? ON the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple) it looks like the one that takes the nonce is:

```
 let credential = OAuthProvider.credential( withProviderID: "apple.com", IDToken: appleIdToken, rawNonce: rawNonce )
```

but the one you're using here takes an access token, not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and Xcode gives a red error and says to change rawNonce to idToken, I also checked the pod files and rawNonce is never mentioned in any project files and the method closest in format is the one I am using.