# "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request."

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-sign-in

I am getting an error using Apple Sign In with Firebase Auth: `"MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request."`

The only other case I've been able to find is similar to the following question, however their solution of updating the pod file does not work.

[Cause of error setting up Sign in with Apple for Firebase in Swift on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011314/cause-of-error-setting-up-sign-in-with-apple-for-firebase-in-swift-on-ios-13)

**Error**:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x2807c6ee0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request.";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request.";
}}}}
```

**Login Button Clicked Method**:

```
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    
    let nonce = randomNonceString()
    currentNonce = nonce
    request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
```

**Section in `ASAuthorizationController`**:

```
    let firebaseCredential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: identityToken!, accessToken: currentNonce)
```

Printing the nonce values after being set, before being sent as a parameter shows that they are indeed the same, added to the appropriate requests, but the service is still giving me this error.

The BundleID is the same in firebase and GoogleService-Info.plist, the app works with Google Sign In and Firebase. I've tried sending the raw nonce, the hashed nonce, different hash methods, everything seems to be okay except for this one thing, and there's no real way to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing the `rawNonce` - you are using the method with `accessToken` instead.

Fix it by doing the following:

```
OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: identityToken!, rawNonce: currentNonce)
```

[In the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016812/9607863), they said that Xcode would mistakingly try fix `rawNonce` to use `accessToken` instead - which is incorrect. The `pod update` fixed the error in this case.

In the Firebase [docs for the iOS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple), they also use the method with the `rawNonce` as you should. You do *not* want to use the hashed nonce here, but rather the value you stored in `currentNonce`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The firebase library has been updated to change "rawNonce" to "accessToken". Also, I'm sending the unhashed, raw nonce, but I have indeed tried sending the hash too. Both have the same error.

Comment: Trying to replace `accessToken` with `rawNonce` causes `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withProviderID:idToken:rawNonce:', expected 'withProviderID:idToken:accessToken:')`

Comment: @SQLiteNoob I'm using the latest version of FirebaseAuth and don't have any issue with the method. I'm using it with Swift Packages, which may be different to pods

Comment: Might be the case with swift packages? The question I linked to also recognized the new accessToken being the correct parameter label?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Hmm. Does adding `accessToken: nil` onto the end fix it?

Comment: Good suggestion, I just tried it. Gave me the same error though. I also took the old pod files from another app and tried adding the method with rawNonce to the pod but that was to no avail either

Comment: How do I go about using it with Swift Packages?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Yeah the method [_is there_](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/23b6acefb9afaf7dc4f5471a14fc087971878072/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/OAuth/FIROAuthProvider.m#L116) in the iOS SDK. To use Swift Packages instead, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app).

Comment: It's not in the Pod - I just tried adding that method to that very file and the header but that just led to another crash. I'll try the Swift Packages route

Comment: Yep, must have a new version that wasn't updating with pods. Thank you for looking at it George

Comment: Hi guys, I faced this issue and update the pod file by pod update but this issue still now remaining. Are you solved this issue?